# How to pass Javascript variable value to wire:click function?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

Thank you for your time.

I have got a View that has a few JavaScript variables with ever-changing values.

I have also implemented a Livewire table. On each row I have got a button that calls a function with `wire:click`

How can I pass the value of a JS variable present the parent View with this `wire:click` call?

Parent View:

```
<script>
var varA=1, varB=2;
<script>
<livewire:component />
```

Livewire Component Blade view:

```
<tr>
<td>{{ $record->name }}</td>
<td>
    <div class="action">
    <button
        wire:click="completed({{ $record->id }})"
    >
        Finish
    </button>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

How can I pass the values of `varA` & `varB` along with `$record->id`?

Comment: It kinda depends on what you are trying to achieve. I am not certain if dynamically changing the `wire:click` will actually send the updated value through. However, you could have a (hidden) input, and bind a `wire:model` to it. Upon changing that with JS, you can trigger a change event and Livewire should pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass this problem by adding an event listener to the button, and through the event listener call the livewire component function and then pass it a JavaScript variable @this.funcionName(JSvariable);

```
<button id="btn">Any Button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', () => {

        let jsVariable = 123;
        let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            @this.livewireFunctionName(jsVariable);
        });

    });
</script>
```